# How to create public directory in internal memory in android

Tags: android, file, memory, directory

I want to create a sub directory which is non-private under the `Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES` directory. I used the code shown below but of no avail. The directory is created but it remains private. I don't know where I'm wrong.

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyImages");
file.mkdirs();
File f = new File(file,"Image1");
```

Comment: "The directory is created but it remains private" -- what do you mean by "private", and how have you determined that this directory is "private"?

Comment: not able to see it in my phone

Comment: How, specifically, are you trying to see it in your phone?

Comment: I tried saving only the image which I can see but when I create a directory and then save that image I cant see it.It might not be private , I want to make that directory public so that even my application is uninstalled I can access those images

Comment: "I cant see it" -- please explain **how you are trying to see it**. Are you using **`adb shell`**? Are you using DDMS? Are you using your own app? Are you using some third-party app? Are you mounting external storage as a drive or volume and are trying to use the file manager of your development machine?

Comment: using file manager. I checked it whether the directory exist or not.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have not created a file, at least in the code that is shown above. You have created a Java `File` object, and you created a directory, but you did not create a file for `Image1`, and so your directory is empty. I know of no way to force your empty directory to be picked up by anything, though you should see it if you use **`adb shell`** or DDMS to examine your device.

When you do eventually write a file to this directory, be sure to call `getFD().sync()` on the `FileOutputStream` before you `close()` that stream. Then, use `MediaScannerConnection` and its static `scanFile()` method to have your newly-created file be indexed by the `MediaStore`. Until you do this, your newly-created file will not be visible via MTP or many third-party apps.

Comment: 'be sure to call getFD().sync() on the FileOutputStream before you close() that stream.'. ? I never saw a getFD.sync() call before. For what is it needed?

Comment: @greenapps: `sync()` on a `FileDescriptor` ensures that the write caching done at the filesystem level has flushed its buffers (`flush()` in Java just flushes the Java buffers). Before you try having a third-party app or the MTP daemon use a file, I recommend `sync()`.

Comment: Ok. But i see no file descriptor as you first said to use it on a file output stream. How would such a statement look like if i have a FileOutputStream?

Comment: @greenapps: "But i see no file descriptor as you first said to use it on a file output stream" -- I wrote "be sure to call `getFD().sync()` on the `FileOutputStream`". `getFD()` is a method on `FileOutputStream` that returns a `FileDescriptor`. `sync()` is a method on `FileDescriptor` that, under the covers, does a classic C-style `fsync()` to block until all buffers are written to disk.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Will have a look.